# Copy one MS Word style from machine to machine?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, styles

I have a complex style named *code* in my Word 2007 normal.dotm document on one machine (setting 'New documents based on this template').

I want to transfer it to another machine (also Word 2007), also to be available in all documents.

I see plenty of tips about transferring styles on **one** machine, but how do I transfer it across (Windows) machines?

BTW In an attempt to recreate the style there is already a style named *code* on the target machine.

Comment: @techie007 I'm talking about one single style, not an entire style set (whatever that may be exactly, I've lost track of all the changes MS made in this area ;-)

Comment: @Jan, The process is much the same I believe, I don't think you can share any one style so it's all or nothing. You can however share the template and copy some text from there to your document to import only that style.